# JSF2 Re-rendering/update ui:repeat list using Ajax

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a ui:repeat list which pulls a bunch of values off my DB & I use it in a jQuery based news-ticker. I am trying to get this list to update/re-render via ajax periodically as I am effectively displaying the latest news entries into my db, using the primefaces p:poll method.

Alternatively I already have a p:poll ajax function working already, that polls the number of items I have stored in my db, which I would like to link to my ui:repeat list to update based on this figure changing, but for now I am simply trying to get it to update!

Here is how the ui:repeat list is compiled:

```
                        <h:form>
                        <div id="ticker-wrapper" class="no-js">
                            <ui:repeat id="newsTickerList" value="#{dbWidgetBean.latestNewsList}" var="newsItem">           
                                <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">

                                    <li class="news-item">                                               
                                        <h:outputLink  value="#{newsItem.rssLink}" target="_blank">
                                            <b><h:outputText value="#{newsItem.indexName}: "/></b>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{newsItem.testFeedLatest}"/>
                                        </h:outputLink>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </div>
                        <p:poll interval="60" listener="#{dbWidgetBean.latestNewsList}" update="newsTickerList"/>
                    </h:form>
```

I have tried various derivatives of the above code & the list is built fine within the @PostConstruct element, but I cant get the list to update!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the surrounding div "ticker-wrapper" tag?
If that doesn't work, replace the div with p:outputPanle and update that.